# Getting different results when integrating with fractions vs decimals

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

**Bug introduced in 13.3**

---

Not sure what in the Mathematica is going here—admittedly I am a beginner.

But these two expressions seem to me that they should produce the same results.

```
Integrate[((0.5 - Cos[ϕ])*Sin[ϕ])/(1.25 - Cos[ϕ])^(3/2), {ϕ, 0, Pi}]

Integrate[((1/2 - Cos[ϕ])*Sin[ϕ])/(5/4 - Cos[ϕ])^(3/2), {ϕ, 0, Pi}]
```

[image: what is going on here]

```
$VersionNumber
```

13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)

Comment: I reproduce OP's result in 13.3/Windows 10.

Comment: Copy-pastable code to reproduce this would be preferred over imaghes.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no code has yet been submitted by the OP or the only answer so far. It would be helpful to list the output of `$Version`  with such Q/As. Up until now, this interaction remains of limited use for site visitors.

Comment: I get zero for both in version: `13.0.1 for Linux x86`

Comment: I reproduce OP's result in `13.3.0 for Windows 10 64 bit x86`.

Comment: Interesting that it works with `NIntegrate`, some symbolic transform goes wrong would be my guess.

Comment: Both 0 in: `13.2.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit)`

Comment: Looks like a bug and should be reported to Wolfram, Inc.

Comment: yes, bug for sure. But in general one should not use real numbers with Integrate. But only exact numbers. For fun, try changing `1.25` to `125/100` and keep the first number as  decimal. Now Integrate returns `0.0` instead of `-0.33333`.  screen shot  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwXS2.png)   V 13.3.1. **Rule of thumb**: use exact numbers with exact functions to be safe.  I have this written on yellow stick on my computer monitor so I do not forget myself.

Comment: Just posted the Version as well as code. Still getting the same results...

Answer (score 5):

There is a workaround in 13.3.1 on Windows 10 and Linux.

```
Integrate[((0.5 - Cos[\[Phi]])*
Sin[\[Phi]])/(1.25 - Cos[\[Phi]])^(3/2), {\[Phi], 0, Pi}, 
 Assumptions -> \[Phi] >= 0]
```

> `4.44089*10^-16`

Comment: Even nonsensical assumptions, like `Assumptions ->ϕ > Pi` of `Assumptions -> x > Pi`, give the correct answer!

Comment: @bbgodfrey: This means the bug is not serious.

Comment: Perhaps, but it should be reported.  Thanks for adding the "bugs" tag.

Answer (score 4):

I get this answer:[image]

Which is basically the same thing. But I could also be wrong.

Comment: What version do you use?

Comment: I get this in version 13.2